# Angular JS app, Flask api app deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, angularjs, heroku, deployment

I have an Angular js application which uses Python-Flask APIs. Both are different apps. In development environment I used grunt reverse proxy to avoid CORS issue. I want to deploy this to Heroku. 
Is it possible to deploy in a single heroku dyno? How to do it?

```
 SampleApp
    client (angularjs)
    server (flask app)
```

Comment: Sure. The AngularJS app is static, so it will serve from the same Heroku dyno.

Comment: @nathancahill do u mean to set the static folder of  flask as angularjs app?

Comment: Yes, Heroku will handle the rest